# Python ctypes not loading dynamic library on Mac OS X

Tags: python, linux, macos, ctypes, dynamic-linking

I have a C++ library `repeater.so` that I can load from Python in Linux the following way:

```
import numpy as np                                    
repeater = np.ctypeslib.load_library('librepeater.so', '.')
```

However, when I compile the same library on Mac OS X (Snow Leopard, 32 bit) and get `repeater.dylib`, and then run the following in Python:

```
import numpy as np                                
repeater = np.ctypeslib.load_library('librepeater.dylib', '.')
```

I get the following error:

```
OSError: dlopen(/mydir/librepeater.dylib, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /mydir/librepeater.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Do I have to do something different to load a dynamic library in Python on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. As the error message says, there's an architecture mismatch between your python and `librepeater.dylib` file. Use `file` to check what the architecture of `librepeater.dylib` is; your python is going to be built using one of the ones not listed.

Comment: Using `file` did the trick: I modified the architecture in the compiler settings to match the python installation and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Were you using the Apple-supplied Python?  If so, you could have just run in 32-bit mode as suggested.  But recompiling works, too. This is also why binaries on OS X are usually built as multi-architecture files (for example, i386, x86_64, and ppc) so the resultant files, libs, or apps can be used on the various kinds of machines supported by the OS level.

Answer (score 11):

It's not just a question of what architectures are available in the dylib; it's also a matter of which architecture the Python interpreter is running in.  If you are using the Apple-supplied Python 2.6.1 in OS X 10.6, by default it runs in 64-bit mode if possible.  Since you say your library was compiled as 32-bit, you'll need to force Python to run in 32-bit mode.  For the Apple-supplied Python, one way to do that is to set a special environment variable:

```
$ python -c "import sys; print sys.maxint"
9223372036854775807
$ export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
$ python -c "import sys; print sys.maxint"
2147483647
```

See Apple's `man 1 python` for more information.